# How to start an application directly (without asking) at startup on Android 4.0

Tags: android

I want to start my application at startup in Android 4.0. To do that, I wrote some codes and these are completely the same with the @Ahmad's codes (in the answer). However, although I select my application as **always**, when tablet opens, it asks 'What do you prefer?' (Android's default launcher or my application). I don't want it to ask that question and it must start my application automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent.

> Broadcast Action: This is broadcast once, after the system has
>   finished booting. It can be used to perform application-specific
>   initialization, such as installing alarms. You must hold the
>   `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in order to receive this broadcast.

In your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Set up a `Broadcastreceiver`:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

This is how your `BroadcastReceiver` could look like:

```
 public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```